# How to merge several data frames of equal format for plotting with ggplot in one digramm in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several data frames (i.e t1, t2 and t3) of same format but maybe with different row lengths.

t1

```
year month avgTemp
2006     1   -0.95
2006     2    1.34
2006     3    3.58
2006     4    9.94
2006     5   14.67
2006     6   18.38
2006     7   23.56
2006     8   16.57
2006     9   18.08
2006    10   13.26
2006    11    8.27
2006    12    4.82
```

t2

```
year month avgTemp
2015     1    3.01
2015     2    2.16
2015     3    6.37
2015     4   10.31
2015     5   14.40
2015     6   17.84
2015     7   22.04
2015     8   21.35
2015     9   14.18
2015    10    9.40
2015    11    8.18
2015    12    7.22
```

and t3

```
year month avgTemp
2005     7   19.79
2005     8   17.54
2005     9   16.69
2005    10   11.64
2005    11    5.40
2005    12    1.97
```

Now, when I want to plot those 3 data frames in one diagramm I am doing this:

```
ggplot() + 
geom_line(data=t1, aes(x = t1$month, y = t1$avgTemp, colour = t1$year)) +
geom_line(data=t2, aes(x = t2$month, y = t2$avgTemp, colour = t2$year)) + 
geom_line(data=t3, aes(x = t3$month, y = t3$avgTemp, colour = t3$year))
```

And the output look like this

[image]

So far everything is ok, but the plot command is very ugly since I have to put every data frame into a new geom_line.
Is there a more elegant way to achieve this by merging the data frames or so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `rbind` to combine all the data frames into one like `t <- rbind(t1, t2, t3)`?

Comment: When I have all data in one data frame then the plot looks different since it is a line plot and it tries to connect the data points with lines. In the plot above you can see that each data frame is an individual line. I want to keep that.

Comment: You can convert the year column into a factor variable, and plot lines per that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
t <- rbind(t1, t2, t3)
t$year <- as.factor(t$year)
ggplot(t, aes(x = month, y = avgTemp, col = year)) + geom_line()
```

It should give you the desired plot with three lines for three years.

EDIT: Adding this code option based on the comment below about leaving year as a numeric value:

```
t <- rbind(t1, t2, t3)
ggplot(t, aes(x = month, y = avgTemp, col = year, group = year)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Ok, that works but I will lose the ability to colorize the line using color gradient since it requires continuous scale.  When I add  scale_colour_gradient2(
      low = "blue",
      mid = "green" ,
      high = "red",
      midpoint = 2010
    )    then I get an error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". Is it possible to keep the continuous scale?

Comment: Added that option above...hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that helped. First I did it wrong but now it works fine.

Comment: At the end, when there will be data from 100 years I want a color flow like in this diagramm. [link](http://www.climate-lab-book.ac.uk/2016/spiralling-global-temperatures/)